# SSRS Aggregate functions can only be used on page headers

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report that is a matrix report by date, so each date is listed across the top of the report and gives the following information

```
_________________Monday___       ___Tuesday  ___         _    _Weekly totals_____
Employee  Emp. hours   emp. lunch   Emp hours   emp lunch   | Emp hours emp lunch 
Krissi         8           .5        3                       |    11          .5
John           8           .5        5              .5       |    13         1.0
```

Then the report gives totals for each row:  Total Employee hours(using the sum function)

The field Employee lunch is calculated(if hours is > 4 lunch = .5)

I tried to use `sum(reporitems!lunch.value)` but get the following error to sum how much time in the calculated field called emp. lunch.

> Aggregate functions can only be used on report items contained in page headers and footers

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: **Aggregate** - not "aggrigate" ....

Comment: why not do all of this in your datasource and just display it in SSRS?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the reportitems collection instead of the fields collection `=SUM(Fields!lunch.Value)` ?

Comment: I can not use the fields, because it is not a field that is currently in the database, it is calculated.

Comment: You might be able to just do something like `=SUM(IIF(Fields!hours.Value > 4, .5, 0))` or whatever you lunch calculation is.